# Which of the TLS protocol versions are secured for enabling in Internet Explorer

Tags: browser, internet-explorer

Which of the versions of the TLS(TLS 1.0,TLS 1.1,TLS 1.2) should be enabled in the Internet Settings of Internet explorer for access of HTTPS sites and secured broswing. Is only one of them enough or which of these are better ones.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you should only enable TLS 1.2. Unfortunately, that won't work so you'll need them all checked at the moment. This is supposed to tell a server you want the highest they'll support. Even then [a few broken HTTPS](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/03/25/misbehaving-https-servers-impair-tls-1.1-and-tls-1.2.aspx) servers will fail but it should be very rare.